# Pyspark subtract abnormal result

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to find the rows of a dataframe that are different from another dataframe so I tried [subtract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract) but I have some strange results.

I take a random line from a dataframe with

```
toSub = df.sample(False, 0.1, seed=0).limit(1)
```

Then I make sure that it is a unique line checking the id from that line, how many time there is in the original dataframe

```
df.filter(df['idCol']=="idFromRandomSample").count()
>>1
```

The original df has

```
df.count()
>>10752732
```

But when I make a subtract I get

```
df.subtract(toSub).count()
>>10749495
```

Why this is diiferent from what I expected which is 10752731. 
Is there a flaw in my logic? Why are there extra lines subtracted? Shouldn't exactly one line be subtracted?

Comment: Is `dfLatest` a typo in the question? (instead of `df`)

Comment: Yes it was and it is corrected

Comment: `note:: This is not guaranteed to provide exactly the fraction specified of the total  count of the given :class:DataFrame` is mentioned in the api document

Comment: @ Ramesh Maharjan Can you say a little more? What is not guaranteed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have duplicates in your data.

Please report

```
toSub.count()

df.dropDuplicates().count()

df.dropDuplicates().subtract(toSub).count()
```

Comment: You were absolutely right. The original data frame had duplicates that subtract removes because it returns a set of the rows